# How to clear recent files list in standalone Microsoft Report Builder app v. 15.0.20073.0 that has stale paths to deleted or moved files?

Tags: sql-server, windows, reporting-services, reportbuilder, recent-file-list

In Microsoft Report Builder Standalone (v. 15.0.20073.0, not Power BI Report Builder, not Visual Studio SSRS) there is a recent files list that does not check existence of the file or give a way to clear out stale entries.

Expectation: the "bad" file path, if clicked, is removed and update the list. Or the file path is checked at launch for existence and removed if not existing. Or can right click on recent file and manually remove if desired.

Actual: Report Builder maintains the recent file path list until it is pushed out by opening enough other rdl files to push it off the list.

**Where is this recent files list stored? How can I manually update or clear it so I'm not clicking on "bad" paths when I re-organize files?**